# Django: customize form input for POST

Tags: django, forms, post

I ran into a problem. I am not an experienced a web-dev(front end), so I would appreciate help.

I am required to create a form in the format below to pass in POST to backend:

key:value

```
{"key":{"key":"value", "key":"value", "key":"value", ..., "key":"value"}}
```

How can I achieve this?

I am working django web framework.

Thank you

**UPDATE:**

I figured it out myself. I used JQuery and JS. I created the form manually using JS and then send via JQuery ajax function. Thanks everybody who tried to help.

Comment: You can try [requests lib](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests)

Answer (score 0):

Start with the tutorial on the docs website perhaps ?

[Django tutorial part 1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/)

Forms is especially covered in chapter 4:

[Chapter 4 : forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial04/)

Comment: thank you for your reply. i already went through the tutorial before. I did django projects before and django is not my problem. My problem is how to create a post request in the format I mentioned above.